# I can't connect to VNC Server (connection refused : error 10061).

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, remote-desktop, ubuntu-12.04, vnc

I purchased a vps and configured it by using this tutorial (means installed GENOM desktop and VNC server):

http://www.time4vps.eu/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=41

Then I installed tiger VNC viewer and Real VNC Viewer plus. I tried to connect to the server by using the server name and also the ip address using the two software. But I am getting :

```
(connection refused : error 10061).
```

What I did :

**I restarted vnc server :**

```
logged in as root.
On terminal : vncserver stop.
On terminal : vncserver start.
```

I googled and found out that, one of the reason may be entering wrong password multiple time. Password have not entered even once, so no chance of entering wrong passwords multiple time.

**I checked with netstat -a. It shows :**

```
0.0.0.0:5900 is listening
```

**I am behind router, so portforwarded the router to local ip and port no.**

All this do not work. Kindly tell me what mistake I am doing. Thanks in advance.

(server is ubuntu server 12.04, client is on win 7 64 bit dektop.)

Answer (score 7):

I was just using ip address. as soon as I used ip:port number, it worked.

Comment: what port number?

Comment: @endolith, check out this answer on SuperUser: [VNC port numbers](https://superuser.com/a/391535/133285)

Comment: +1 I had to add the port number 5901. I think the port is not needed for most VNC clients if the VNC server is running on port 5900 (the client is guessing the port).